# How to stop hist from printing all the information into the console

Tags: r, histogram, lapply

I have a list of 4 data sets and I want to plot histograms based on each element of my list (each data set) into one graph. Let's say I would like to plot histograms of column means for each matrix. Here is a code that I am using:

```
my.data <- replicate(3, list(replicate(10, rnorm(20))))
lapply(my.data, function(x){hist(colMeans(x))})
```

I know how to plot multiple graphs on one figure but I don't know how to suppress printing of the histogram information.

Comment: `invisible(lapply(...))`

Comment: is it going to print the graphs?

Comment: Give it a try and see.

Comment: @Zheyuan Li I tried that but it was still printing everything once I called the variable to get the plots out

Comment: @Rich Scriven I did and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Rich Scriven `invisible(lapply(...))` solves the problem. I thought I would re-post the answer from comments here so that my question does not hang in the air as unanswered.